# SimpleDateFormat and Date object

Tags: java, android, date

In my android app I retrieve from an api the current day as.

```
   long dateTime = innerJSON.getLong("dt");

   Date weekDay = new Date(dateTime * 1000L);

   SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new  
   SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
   String day = outFormat.format(weekDay);
```

And I get the current day ie Monday.

For the date I use the same Date object but with a different SimpleDateFormat object.

```
  SimpleDateFormat outFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
  String date = outFormat1.format(weekDay);
```

And that gives me,

```
  28-5-2016
```

which is fine. However, I want the date to have a format of

```
  28 May
```

Any ideas on that? I checked the official orarcle's [site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html),but I can't find a solution.

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat outFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
```

you will get the output you required.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `dd MMM` format here.

[More details provided here in official documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat outFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
String date = outFormat1.format(weekDay);
```

Answer (score 1):

haha. That was easy.

```
SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
```

It's summer now and sunny,so I can't concetrate:):)